# Tomcat application with self-signed certificate results in ERR_CERT_AUTHORITY_INVALID in the Chrome browser

Tags: apache, tomcat, ssl, certificate

Tomcat application with self-signed certificate results in ERR_CERT_AUTHORITY_INVALID in the Chrome browser

I've set up a https and created a self-signed certificate. However, when I connect to the URL, I get a ERR_CERT_AUTHORITY_INVALID message.

https://{remote_host_name}:8443/

I've followed the instructions on the Tomcat website for SSL and self-signed certificates ( https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/ssl-howto.html#Edit_the_Tomcat_Configuration_File ). One difference is that I'm connecting to a remote host, not a localhost, although I dont think that should matter.

This is a test environment, but unfortunately I cannot add an exception for the certificate in the browsers of the test hosts, as they create new FF profiles each test run.

Here is the command I have used to create the self-signed cert:

```
./keytool -genkey -keyalg RSA -alias tomcat -keystore /var/tomcat/.keystore -storepass changeit -validity 360 -keysize 2048
```

Here is my Tomcat server.xml connector information:

```
Connector port="8443" protocol="org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol"
maxThreads="150" SSLEnabled="true" scheme="https" secure="true"
clientAuth="false" sslProtocol="TLS"
keystoreFile="/var/tomcat/.keystore"
keystorePass="changeit"
```

- Does the config in the Tomcat doc for self-signed certs only work when running Tomcat on localhost?
- What is the best way to
  resolve this?

Answer (score 5):

> Tomcat application with self-signed certificate results in ERR_CERT_AUTHORITY_INVALID in the Chrome browser

Of course it does. Your tomcat server is presenting the browser a certificate which is not issued by a certificate agency trusted by the browser (i.e. shipped with the browser or with the OS). Thus the browser has no reason to trust the certificate and complains.

If the browser would check not if it trusts the issuer of the certificate this would mean that it would trust any certificate issued by some arbitrary person, which would include certificates issued by an attacker. Do you really want this?

To work with self-signed certificates you have to explicitly accept the certificate as trusted in each browser, but of course only after you've validated the fingerprint of the certificate manually to make sure that nobody has tampered with the connection. No server side reconfiguration can make the browser automatically trust such self-signed certificates. The only way to skip this step is to use certificates issued by a certificate agency already trusted by the browser.

Comment: A  great example is to perform a POST from some arbitrary site to your local machine (simulating an injection attack on that site sending stolen information to your server). If the browser didn't step in to double-check with the user, then that injection would mean incredibly easy information theft.

Chrome's message is appropriate: "Attackers might be trying to steal your information from {url} (for example, passwords, messages, or credit cards). NET::ERR_CERT_AUTHORITY_INVALID"